# How to generate all possible permutations of an object list, starting with the empty list?

Tags: python, permutation, python-2.x

Not a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset) because that answer deals with permuting literals, and this question refers to objects. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011559/object-list-permutations-are-not-independent-from-one-another-in-python) for what happens when permuting objects.

Using python 2.

I need to generate all possible permutations of an object list that includes the empty list, and then all permutations of 1 object, then with 2 and so on.

I have found a way to do this with a string:

```
import itertools
stuff = [1, 2, 3]
for idx in range(len(stuff)+1):
    for i in itertools.permutations('ABCD', idx):
        print i

Sample output:
()

('A',)

('B',)

('C',)

('D',)

('A', 'B')

('A', 'C')

('A', 'D')

('B', 'A')
.
.
.
.

('D', 'C', 'A')

('D', 'C', 'B')
```

What I need is to do this with a custom object list. I tried to apply the above algorithm to an objects list. My solution below:

```
originalObjectList = A list of many custom objects.
allPossibleOrderings=[]

for idx in range(len(originalObjectList)+1):
    originalObjectListOrderings = list(itertools.permutations(originalObjectList, idx))
    for objects in originalObjectListOrderings:
        allPossibleOrderings.insert(0, map(copy.copy,objects))
```

The problem with this implementation is that the allPossibleOrderings list doesn't contain all permutations, only the last 29. It's as if when I insert new permutations, it overwrites old ones.

Comment: The "duplicate" doesn't seem to be exactly the same, but the idea is the same. You just need to replace `combinations` with `permutations`. Also, your first example looks fine, but you strayed from copying the same procedure for some reason.

Comment: The [issue you say that makes this question not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011559/object-list-permutations-are-not-independent-from-one-another-in-python) -- that modifying object properties inside of a loop causes references to those objects to reflect the changed values -- is not present in the sample code you've provided, since you are not modifying the objects you are permuting.  I put together a code pen and ran your above code.  The issue does not reproduce: https://trinket.io/python/0a90c10c28

Comment: (This is to say, I suspect you have simplified the code you are showing too much and are leaving out a critical portion of the original code which is causing the issue you are observing.)